# Fragmentation involving formation of enamine

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I have a problem on fragmentation which requires mechanisms involving formation of an enamine from a cyclic ketone and cyclic secondary amine. This then reacts with a cyclic aldehyde via conjugate addition, but the intermediate cannot be reached.

I've been told that I have to exchange the enamine of the ketone with the enamine of the aldehyde. What does this mean?

> **PROBLEM 17**
>
> Give mechanisms for these reactions, commenting on the fragmentation.
>
> [image: Rxn scheme]
>
> **Purpose of the problem**
>   Revision of conjugate addition of enols, another ring expansion with an enolate as leaving group and an interesting piece of stereochemistry.
>
> **Suggested solution**
>   The first step is enamine formation and the second is conjugate addition. This appears to lead to a dead end as we cannot find a way to make the intermediate from the product.

Comment: The product looks like it is at the wrong oxidation level, are you sure there isn't a double bond in the [7] ring?

Comment: I believe it means you should convert the ketiminium back to a ketone and then use the pyrrolidine to make an aldiminium.

Answer (score 4):

@Laura: Both Waylander and Zhe are correct in their respective comments. Your example is from the work of Hendrickson and Boeckman.<sup>[1](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00734a070?journalCode=jacsat&quickLinkVolume=93&quickLinkPage=1307&selectedTab=citation&volume=93)</sup> Enamine **1** and conjugated aldehyde **2** were mixed neat forming bridged aminoketone **3**. At some point, as Zhe has intimated, exchange of pyrrolidine from the ketone to the aldehyde must occur before cyclization to **3** can be accomplished. The usual explanation is that traces of water are present to catalyze the reaction. Quaternization of the amino group in **3** affords the salt **4** which cleaves with hydroxide via a Grob-like fragmentation to **5**. Note the important anti arrangement of the dotted bond and the proximate vicinal bold bond. The product contains a double bond as Waylander has stated. The first example of this reaction, **6** --> **9**, was reported by Stork and Landesman<sup>[2](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01600a088?journalCode=jacsat&quickLinkVolume=78&quickLinkPage=5129&selectedTab=citation&volume=78)</sup> in 1956.

[image]
1) [J. B. Hendrickson and R. K. Boeckman, Jr., *J. Am. Chem. Soc.*, **1971**, *93*, 1307.](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00734a070?journalCode=jacsat&quickLinkVolume=93&quickLinkPage=1307&selectedTab=citation&volume=93)
2) [G. Stork and H. K. Landesman, *J. Am. Chem. Soc.*, **1956**, *78*, 5129.](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01600a088?journalCode=jacsat&quickLinkVolume=78&quickLinkPage=5129&selectedTab=citation&volume=78)